# android -What is the best way to play video in my application

Tags: android, android-video-player, android-videoview

I've encounter this problem many times , the problem is that I've a videoView in my application but it couldn't play lots of different formats and video files.

for example , if I want to open a mp4 file, I should ask my users to convert the video to a H.264 format and then upload  the file and it's very hard.

I'm looking for a better way to play various formats of videos .

Does any one no any way to do so ? have can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use a third party library, [FFmpegMediaPlayer](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer) is a  is a reimplementation of Android's MediaPlayer class based on FFmpeg. It adds support for additional formats and protocols not provided by Android's MediaPlayer class. It is licensed under LGPLv2.1.

Answer (score 1):

In android, .mp4 extension is the most common video format which is compatible for the default playback.

**Objective**:

1. Implemention of VideoView for the playback of Videos.
2. Usage of MediaController for the playback controls.
3. SurfaceView which will hold the playback of Videos.

**Containers that are used for playing videos:**

[VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html)

[MediaController](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html)

[SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html)

[DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html)

Read more: http://mrbool.com/how-to-play-video-formats-in-android-using-videoview/28299#ixzz3uUX2Bew0

Or for getting best answer , you need to see this link.

[Best way to play a Video file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099811/best-way-to-play-a-video-file)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try out [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer). It has really nice features and documentations. Try this codelabs tutorial. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro/#0